Request change name tokenpair
I already changed the token name of my coin on dextools and dexscreener, because people will buy with you too the most, I would love if you can change the name from GTA to GTA6
Ca DosKVpFhk7D1uBqddDTYNLCVdqNFHtmw1PbvVyNQqPf2
I can't on chain because I'm the cto leader, not the developer, the coin has no Metadata whatsoever.
Thanks

You will need the updateAuthority Keypair for this, otherwise, you cannot change the metadata of a token you have no authority over.
The updateAuthority should also not be revoked otherwise this will fail.
Doing this with code using Metaplex libraries.
async function updateTokenMetadata() {
    const mint = publicKey("");

    const initialMetadata = await fetchMetadataFromSeeds(umi, { mint });
    await updateV1(umi, {
        mint,
        authority: umi.identity,
        data: { ...initialMetadata, name: "GTA6" },
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi);
}

ref: https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/update
